# Tagging in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, tags

I have followed a post here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-using-tags/

But when I try to add custom tags they dont save when pushing enter or clicking save.

[image]

Is it a bug or am I missing the point? Note that I cant even save the built in tags.

thanks
Russ

Comment: strange. usually this is the idea. I just checked with tagging a Resource Group and it was successful. What type of resource you are trying to tag ?

Comment: @astaykov. I just tried to tag a web app. I'll try again tomorrow and see what happens. Thanks man

Comment: again strange - I also tried web app and with success. Can you try empty your browsers cache and try again.

Comment: @astaykov that worked. Thanks for your help. I would say the entry form for tags is a bit unreliable. I had to close the blade a couple of times as it had a seizure!! Also, I can't mark your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correct impression about the use of tags. Depending on what type of resource you are trying to tag, there might be some transient errors or glitches in the UI.

As I could successfully tag a Resource Group and a Web App, can you delete your browsers cache and reaload the portal to check if this would solve the issue. Before all, this portal is still in Preview and some glitches from time to time are expected.